# Move file to a new folder that happens to have the same file name in Python

Tags: python

Within in my script it's very rare that I run into this problem where I'm trying to move a file to this new folder that already happens to have a file with the same name, but it just happened.  So my current code uses the shutil.move method but it errors out with the duplicate file names.  I was hoping I could use a simple if statement of checking if source is already in destination and change the name slightly but can't get to that work either.  I also read another post on here that used the distutils module for this issue but that one gives me an attribute error.  Any other ideas people may have for this?

I added some sample code below.  There is already a file called 'file.txt' in the 'C:\data\new' directory.  The error given is Destination path already exist.

```
import shutil
myfile = r"C:\data\file.txt"
newpath = r"C:\data\new"
shutil.move(myfile, newpath)
```

Comment: Some example code, errors?

Comment: Please add code that demonstrates the problem. This should be **small** and **runnable** *on its own* and reproduce the problem. This makes it far easier to start looking for solutions and will improve the quantity, quality and clarity of answers as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip guys, I should have been better about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check that the file exists with [`os.path.exists`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists) and then remove it if it does.

```
import os
import shutil
myfile = r"C:\data\file.txt"
newpath = r"C:\data\new"
# if check existence of the new possible new path name.
check_existence = os.path.join(newpath, os.path.basename(myfile))
if os.path.exists(check_existence):
    os.remove(check_existence)
shutil.move(myfile, newpath)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.4 you can try the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html) module. This is just an example so you can rewrite this to be more efficient/use variables:

```
import pathlib
import shutil

myfile = r"C:\data\file.txt"
newpath = r"C:\data\new"

p = pathlib.Path("C:\data\new")
if not p.exists():
   shutil.move(myfile, newpath)
#Use an else: here to handle your edge case.
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, I would have used if I was using 3.4.

Comment: @Jim, I don't think this actually solves the OP's problem: in the OP's example, `newpath` is a directory that always exists.  The issue was that there was a file in that directory called `file.txt`, and _that file_ was what needed to be checked for existence.  Apart from that, nice answer.

Comment: @CodyPiersall thanks for pointing that out. I'm still learning Python myself so I appreciate the feedback. I will leave the answer here, because there might be something useful in it for Python 3 if people stumble across it. Also I upvoted your answer.